# Do I need to whitelist any IPs to use Mandrill API?

Tags: php, email, mandrill, whitelist

I am trying to send mail using `Mandrill API` and I have got following responses :

```
[{"email":"_emailid_","status":"queued","_id":"772237d78ce74e5c9bd8ccbd9a1cfb8c"}]
{"email":"_emailid_","status":"scheduled","_id":"10a0b596a95e44ddb5e8cf504e3899ce","reject_reason":null},    
{"email":"_emailid_","status":"scheduled","_id":"b699d58f021b43b2a0b25d801d1b4f91","reject_reason":null}
```

But I am not getting any mail on the email addresses sent. Please help.
Do I need to whitelist the IP of the system from where I am doing the curl call ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to whitelist any ip addresses, you however do have to configure the DNS records for your email domain properly, head over to the domain settings page in the mandrill control panel for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine.Either your you are not providing correct email to api or mail are coming to your spam folder.You need to check mail from address which you give to the api.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least the last two were scheduled, which means they won't send immediately, but rather at the scheduled time in the future. You'll probably want to double check the time and date that they were scheduled to be sure.

For the first one, there are a number of reasons that emails are queued, including if they have attachments that need to be scanned, or if they're part of a large/batch API call. We'd need more information about the API parameters that you passed to determine the reason for it being queued and/or what happened once it was queued.

You can [search your Outbound Activity](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22211902-How-do-I-search-my-outbound-activity-in-Mandrill-) by the recipient email address, subject line, sender, and a number of other criteria for emails that have been sent. Messages that are scheduled but haven't sent yet cannot be searched since they've not been processed. For any messages that have sent, click on the word "Delivered" on the Outbound Activity page to see more details about the response that Mandrill got from the receiving server when delivering the message.